# Cumulative Sum like MS Excel in Pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

**Input:**

```
    DEBIT             CREDIT                 
 0   10                20                   
 1   5                 30                                 
 2   6                 5
```

**Expected Output:**

```
    DEBIT             CREDIT                BALANCE 
 0   10                20                   10
 1   5                 30                   35              
 2   6                 5                    34
```

I want to do `cumulative sum of difference of CREDIT and DEBIT column` to get the BALANCE column. That is

```
Balance(1st value) =  CREDIT(1st value) - DEBIT(1st value)
Balance(2nd value) = Balance(1st value) + CREDIT(2nd value) - DEBIT(2nd value)
Balance(3rd value) = Balance(2nd value) + CREDIT(3rd value) - DEBIT(3rd value)
```

Comment: please post in the question a sample of your data not as image

Comment: Please provide your data as text, also include your excel formulas for clearance

Comment: I have added edited my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sample DataFrame:

**df:**

```
    C   D
0   1.0 4.0
1   1.0 2.0
2   3.0 2.0
3   3.0 7.0
```

---

Take difference between D and C column using `pd.diff()` and thne do cumilative sum using `.cumsum()`

---

```
df['bal'] = df.diff(axis=1).iloc[:,1].cumsum()
```

---

**df:**

```
    C   D   bal
0   1.0 4.0 3.0
1   1.0 2.0 4.0
2   3.0 2.0 3.0
3   3.0 7.0 7.0
```

---

For the given DataFrame:

```
df['BALANCE'] = df[['DEBIT', 'CREDIT']].diff(axis=1).iloc[:,1].cumsum().astype(int)
```

---

**df:**

```
    DEBIT   CREDIT  BALANCE
0   10      20      10
1   5       30      35
2   6       5       34
```